# How to prevent Mudblazor Mudtable to wrap table into card view on mobile phone

Tags: responsive, mudblazor

How can I prevent ModTable to automatically change the table view to a "card" view when displaying on a mobile phone. I would love to scroll horizontally through the table instead of having it as cards scrolling vertically.

[image]

[image]

Sorry for describing it so badly, it seems I'm missin the right terms.

Best regards
radi5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://mudblazor.com/components/table#default-table)

> The default table displays your data in simple rows and is responsive, it breaks into mobile layout on Breakpoint.Xs unless changed.
> Add the DataLabel property to your MudTd cells to properly display the column label when the table has changed to mobile layout.
>
> The table can be prevented from breaking into mobile layout by setting the Breakpoint to Breakpoint.None.

So you will need to set the `Breakpoint` property to none.

```html
<MudTable Items="@Elements.Take(4)" Breakpoint="Breakpoint.None">
    <!-- table content -->
</MudTable>
```

[MudBlazor snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QYcdlalkSUjyHfnA)

Comment: Thanks a lot @RBee, read through it 10 times but missed it anyway!

Comment: Np, I had to try various keywords to find it too.